# Which icon does indicator-power use when fully charged?

Tags: power-management, icons, indicator, battery

This is a minor annoyance. Using Xubuntu 14.04. I installed the latest Faenza icon set. Unfortunately, it's missing the icon for when the battery is fully charged (adapter is connected).

It looks like this:

[image]

(the blank icon next to volume)

As soon as I unplug, it will change to appropriate icons (discharging, or if I plug it back in, charging).

I can use any of the other faenza icons to be displayed when it's charged, it's just that I don't know which one the indicator-power is looking for.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the icon is called `battery-full-symbolic` or `battery-full-charge-symbolic`. You could place the image in the path:

```
~/.icons/<THEME_NAME>/status/scalable/battery-full-symbolic.svg
```

and/or

```
~/.icons/<THEME_NAME>/status/scalable/battery-full-charge-symbolic.svg
```

To check for the actual paths used run:

```
locate battery-full | grep /usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono
```

in a terminal.

Comment: All those files are already present :/

Comment: But are they present under `~/.icons/Faenza/`... ?

Comment: Yes. Actually one was missing, but I duplicated an existing one. Upon further inspection, I noticed elementary-xfce and elementary-xfce-dark icon sets (default in Xubuntu) have a panel folder inside icons, which features said icons. The problem is that even when copying the entire panel folder, I still get that ugly thing in the system tray. Super annoyting.

Comment: Do other icon themes work fine? Maybe it's a bug on the panel or the indicator (and you might want to report it). Also notice that the last command I show above lists path with specific sizes (22, 24) instead of "scalable".